# How to set tab indentation to 2 space in atom?

Tags: python, atom-editor, styling, pylint

I have changed the setting two the following:

```
Soft Tabs: On
Tab Length: Default (2)
Tab Type: soft
```

Still, when I program in python I get this output:

```
...
for x in buf.getvalue().split("\n"):
    output = io.StringIO()
...
```

Which gives me 4 spaces, instead of 2. Any idea where I am getting things wrong?

Comment: I don't have an answer for your question, but you should probably follow PEP guidelines, which tell you to use 4 spaces as indentation.

Comment: The main thing you're doing wrong is wanting 2 space indents. :) Please see https://stackoverflow.com/a/6338054/4014959

Comment: Haha. Well, style guides. Have to follow.